# created a small framework but showing init error in swift

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I am trying to create my first framework ,

What I am trying to do is, I have added one public method to read the config json (dictionary) from app level. So I need app to pass this config dictionary and read using framework.

I have add framework all correctly and then imported it in app and tried to create instance but getting  following error

“ 'Platform' initializer is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection leve
“

Here. “Platform is framework name.

**Here is the code in framwork side**

```
import Foundation

public class Platform {

   public init(){

    }



    public func readConfigFileFromApp(config:Dictionary<String, String>)  {

        print (config)

        //Read the configfile from app and save it here for rest of the SDK use

    }

}
```

**On app side i tried this line**

```
import UIKit
import Platform
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let platform = Platform() . **//Getting error 'Platform' initializer is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level**
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}
```

please help

Comment: How are you importing your framework into your project? Are you sure that your project is using the latest version (Presumably your `init` wasn't public initially). Have you tried cleaning your project?  Stylistically, why have an empty `init` and then a separate `readConfigFileFromApp` function?  Why not simply `init(config:[String:String])`?  Presumably you can't use your `Platform` instance without first calling `readConfigFileFromApp`?

Comment: `public init() {}` is correct, can you try cleaning the build folder, rebuild and reimport the framework

Comment: yes i have tried all above still same erro

Comment: i deleted ansd restarted xcode and its working